# Why is npm start closing immediatly my frontend container with a clean exit code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

## ⬇ Context ⬇

I have an application built thanks to `docker-compose` with 3 services as follows:

- backend: `django` REST API,
- frontend: `react.js`,
- `nginx` for proxying everything.

My question is about the frontend only in a dev environment, and more precisely about the development server which does something weird I am not able to understand.

---

## ⬇ The issue I am facing with ⬇

When I run `docker-compose nginx up` while logging my frontend service, **development server will output (as expected) `Starting the development server...`, but will make my frontend service to close immediatly with a clean exit (code 0)** (as if my `entrypoint.dev.sh` reached its end). But before, this did not happen like that, development server was set up and my frontend service was able to run as expected.

I noticed that if I add a `sleep 1000m` at the end of my `entrypoint.dev.sh`, then I get inside the container `docker exec -it frontend sh`, I will be able to run `npm start` and to keep the development server up as expected.

I don't know what changed in my setup. Maybe an update of my MacOS Docker client? Not even sure.

---

## ⬇ My configuration ⬇

This is how my frontend service is defined through my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  frontend:
    build: 
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    environment:
      VAR: STUFF
      [...]
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/app/frontend/src
      - ./frontend/entrypoint.dev.sh:/app/frontend/entrypoint.dev.sh
      - ./frontend/package.json:/app/frontend/package.json
    entrypoint: /bin/sh /app/frontend/entrypoint.dev.sh
```

My `entrypoint.dev.sh` looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "FRONTEND - DEV"
npm install -g npm
npm install
npm start
```

---

## ⬇ Question ⬇

**Do you know why am I facing with this behavior?** I spent too much time trying to figure out what was the problem, and even if I am now able to run the dev server while inside the frontend container, this is not satisfying, it does not feel right.

Many thanks for your help!